# Can personalized custom (database) data be added to a post using the wordpress API

Tags: wordpress, api

Ok, so how do I put this simply and sweetly. It's a wordpress issue

```
        $post = array(
            'post_type'     => $type,
            'post_title'    => $title,
            'post_content'  => $content,
            'post_status'   => $status,
            'post_name' => $slug
        );
        wp_insert_post($post);
```

The code above creates a post, but I'd like my post to be able to hold custom key => values of my own choosing instead of simple html "content".

I'm pulling several values of information (title, category, summary, thumbnail_url) from an external RSS feed. At the moment, I am just formatting it into html and adding it all to a page as "content", whereas I'd prefer to be able to store this information as it is, so that each individual value can be accessed relative to the 'post' it's attached to and modified later on, on a whim.

```
i.e $page = get_page_by_title('title');
    $summary = $page('summary);
```

I want to create several "posts" with their own custom values (title, category, summary, thumb, url).

I also want to display all of these "posts" on one 'page', but that's a question for another time.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [add_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta) function along with the return value of `wp_insert_post` to insert the custom data as custom fields.

```
    $post = array(
        'post_type'     => $type,
        'post_title'    => $title,
        'post_content'  => $content,
        'post_status'   => $status,
        'post_name' => $slug
    );
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($post);
    add_post_meta($post_id, "title", "Behind Foo Bars");
```

Then you can retrieve it with [get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)

```
get_post_meta($post_id, "title");
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Clean, simple and EXACTLY what I wanted.